# Flutter Google sign in & registering users

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, registration

I have currently used google sign in for my flutter app. So, when registering users using their gmail is there any possible way to insert some additional data to the users collection. **Currently I can only enter the users' gmail related data like (Photo URL, email, display Name etc.)**

Thank you.

Comment: create your own copy of userdata and add to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a new screen with a form with additional fields that you need and insert data into the firestore user collection or via API.
if the user logs in again for some reason, you can query for records and show another(home/dashboard) screen in that case.

Comment: yes thank you. after going through many options this is the only option to use. thank you.